# Chat backwards?

Tags: discussion, chat, notifications, unicode

Recently in chat we were having this thing about things being backwards. However, I noticed it affects other things like stared questions and desktop notifications when I'm pinged. All the text becomes backwards, including those like "Xh ago by User". This is what I mean: [image: Chat error]

And for the ping notification: 
[image]

We can see that "5h ago by fredley" is backwards, even though it should not be. We can also see that "The Bridge" is backwards. Is this a bug or am I missing out on some easter eggs?

Comment: Can you link the post?

Comment: @PatrickHofman [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22209384#22209384) you go

Comment: ‫‬‭‮‪‫‬‭‮҉PLet's see...

Comment: Well, as long as chat allows unicode those things will happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a Unicode [right-to-left override mark](http://unicode-table.com/en/202E/).

The code of the original post:

```
@UniKitty &#8238; etc.
```

This is not a bug in the SE code, it is just someone pulling a joke with Unicode characters.

I repeat: **‮It is not a bug!**

Which is:

```
I repeat: **&#8238;It is not a bug!**
```

Comment: There's magic here, my magical word reverser can't flip that phrase in bold.

Comment: @UniKitty Copy the bold text. Paste in Notepad. Select first character. Delete. The text will magically get back to normal. No need in fancy non working reverser tools.

Comment: My brain just died from weirdness. This is too weird for me. My cursor jumps around, but it works

Answer (score 6):

That's Unicode for you; insert a [Right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) and the *remainder of the text* is reversed.

You can do so in regular posts too ‮but any trolling will get you some moderator attention.

Also see the [HTML specifications on *Language information and text direction*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html); it depends on the exact HTML structure as to where exactly the right-to-left direction is reversed again.

Comment: Let the Unicode games begin!

Comment: @PatrickHofman PLZ NO!